# How to compute （row) basis of a sparse matrix in Eigen library?

Tags: sparse-matrix, eigen, basis

I am wondering how to extract a (row） basis of a sparse matrix using sparse QR decomposition or other sparse decomposition in Eigen library? When I say a basis, I mean a vector of row indices such that the corresponding rows form a basis of the matrix

I can use the sparse QR decomposition in Eigen to compute the nullspace of a sparse matrix.
The code works like the following

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> m_matrix;
qr.compute(m_matrix.transpose());
Eigen::MatrixXd Q = qr.matrixQ();
Eigen::MatrixXd kernel = Q * Eigen::MatrixXd::Identity(cols, cols).rightCols(cols - qr.rank());
```

But I am not sure how to extract a basis

Comment: Do you mean a basis of the image of the matrix?

Comment: I mean the basis of the row space of the matrix. If you make a transpose, then that is the image of the matrix (colum space)

Comment: If you already calculated `Q` as above, it would be just `Q.leftCols(qr.rank())`, wouldn't it? (N.B. `kernel` is just `Q.rightCols(cols-qr.rank())` -- no need to do a matrix multiplication).

Comment: Yes, but I need to get the indices of the corresponding columns, not just a basis. So the columns corresponding to the indices form a basis. For example, if column 1 and 3 form a basis, which means I can remove column 2 and keep the rank the same, then (1,3) is the indices set I want to get.

Comment: Take the first `qr.rank()` elements of [`qr.colsPermutation()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseQR.html#aa27f024fe063684754047c531ab84a2b)